# Remove indent in table in HTML

Tags: html, html-table, indentation

I want to indent the text "Did you forget your username instead" to the position where the text "username" is.

Screenshot of what it looks like and you'll understand what I mean:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/06tzFPt.png]

```
</td>
</tr></tbody></table><table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFBF00">
<tbody><tr>
</tr><tr>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php"></form>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#D8D8D8">

<tbody><tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>

</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Forgot your password? </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Did you forget <a href=http://www.google.com>your username</a> instead? <br></br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">

</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>

</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
</div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for `colspan`

Remove the two columns before the 'Did you forget...' column like this:

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/nKx3U/

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">Did you forget <a href=http://www.google.com>your username</a> instead? <br></br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</tr>
```

I am also not sure if a table is the best option for this.